# Can't find YouTube Data API v3 in the Google Developers Console

Tags: android, youtube

I'm looking into the possibility of embeding youtube player inside an android application. I downloaded the sample project from:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/sample-applications

and upon running I found out I need to enter the API key from google developers console. I try to follow the steps explained here:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application

but the problem is, I don't have a "YouTube Data API v3" position on the list of API's, as you can see from this screenshot:
https://db.tt/Vc1TOf6N

I'm stumped... I've looked on the web for similar case, but I can't find anything. Do I have to do something first for this option to be visible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this url to access the old version of the Developers console:
https://code.google.com/apis/console/?noredirect 
select your project, then select Services and scroll down till the end of the page, you will find YouTube Data API v3.

Comment: Oh man, what a bug in google console and docs... Thanks a lot for pointing that. Indeed there is youtube api there.

Comment: anytime, I'm happy that it helped. I also wonder why Google sometimes confuses us like that!